# Applications License Types

Tags: smartface.io

I have upgraded my license from Community to Individual, the applications created before "individual" upgrade  are in "Community License". How to change the already produced application license to individual? I have deleted  application and recreate but it does not accept that and gives "This app ID exists. Please select a different ID"?

Answer (score 0):

The application that is published on store, has a bundle id, and you need to use the same bundle id in order to update it.
Therefore, regardless of which licence you have, you should use the same bundle id for your new version too.
But because you have an individual licence, you can use your own splash screen (not the default one).

And also, because you have an individual licence, for your new applications you can use custom bundle id.

Comment: It means to make update on app store existing apps produced by community license i should create new app license with individual license  and change bundle id with existing one on Xcode? In order to avoid "developer info" message?